# php date() giving result 1 day ahead

Tags: php, date

I'm attempting to use PHP's `date()` function to search my database for today's date, but the result is always for tomorrows date.

This code:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

is currently giving me `2018-08-02`, but it should be `2018-08-01`

I've seen many questions on StackOverflow for this question:

- [Date function in PHP gives always date one day behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500442/date-function-in-php-gives-always-date-one-day-behind)
- [php dates off by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621665/php-dates-off-by-one-day)
- [Adding one day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394791/adding-one-day-to-a-date)
- [php date ("Y/m/d") is one day off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759185/php-date-y-m-d-is-one-day-off)

The solution is the same on all of them; use `date_default_timezone_set()`, but I am already doing that in my index.php file.

```
date_default_timezone_set("US/Central");
```

I'm using a PHP framework, the index.php file is *always* loaded, no matter where I am in my application, and `date_default_timezone_set()` is the 2nd line ran for my whole application.

How can I make `date()` report the correct date?

Comment: dump date_default_timezone_get(); before query, maybe your framework somewhere rewrite your call, also try to set it via phpini

Comment: What's the exact date? E.g. `var_dump(date('c'));`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `string(10) "2018-08-02"`

Comment: Did you see the [list of PHP supported TZ](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)? `US/Central` is not in...

Comment: @RingØ I tried `America/Chicago` as well

Comment: set timezone to UTC like this 

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC')

and then try date fn.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is with the server's date itself. Make sure your server's date is correct.

Comment: What does `date` from the shell return? Maybe your server's clock is wrong.

Comment: @bxN5 I can't really dump it right before the query, because it's inside a class and I don't get any output. I did it on my view page however, and it said `US/Central`. I'll try phpini

Comment: @AlexHowansky It's looking like that may be the problem, I'm getting `Thu Aug  2 12:43:16 EDT 2018`

Comment: NTP is your friend ;-)

Comment: Please run the statement I suggested or a similar one. I'd like to figure out the exact full date with hours, minutes, seconds and time zone.

Comment: your server timezone is +2:30hrs

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `string(25) "2018-08-02T11:53:34-05:00"`

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you, issue fixed by changing server timezone. Should this question be deleted?

Comment: No, don't delete, it's a valid question with a comment thread that might be helpful to others.

Comment: The time appears to be correct but the system clock is certainly one day ahead. Probably not a PHP issue at all.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, it was the time on the server itself that was wrong.